# Twitter bootstrap image gallery with a thumbnail carousel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a bootstrap carousel where has a thumbnail carousel with big images. I found an image gallery carousel something like this:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/

I need the same functionality by using bootstrap carousel. My design is something like this one:
[image]
Does anyone make it possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider

Comment: @ketan, thanks for such a resource. But I really need to make this carousel using bootstrap only. Any better help can I get from you?

Answer (score 1):

Owl Carousel is best plugin for all types carousels.

I think you are looking for this: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/sync.html

[image: Owl Carousel]

Comment: Owl carousel is simply awesome. But I need to make it using bootstrap carousel. I did not find any example which I want. :/

Comment: @RonySatiar: check these: 

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/W0oq6  -------

http://codepen.io/RetinaInc/pen/xbLgK -------

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanarvizu/JS6JV/16/light/

Comment: thanks. I am searching something like this example. I'll make it as my design.